# Url checking does not work properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

In my TableViewController I'm using custom cells. I'm displaying some data about the companies. Company title is colored blue by default, and I'm checking if company does not have valid url so I can paint it black. Of course, I added a logic to forbid opening companies website if the company does not have valid Url.

However, every time this table view is displayed, there are several companies with valid urls who's titles are painted black.

So, I'm using same logic for coloring the titles and opening urls in safari, but coloring does not work properly, and opening in safari does.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath function

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StandardSearchResultCell";

    ResultsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    Data *theData = [Data getInstance];
    Company *theCompany = [theData.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lblTitle.text = theCompany.DisplayName;

    cell.lblDescription.text = theCompany.Description;
    cell.lblAddressPt1.text = theCompany.AddressPt1;
    cell.lblAddressPt2.text = theCompany.AddressPt2;
    cell.lblPhone.text = theCompany.Phone;
    cell.lblEmail.text = theCompany.Email;

    cell.lblDescription.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false;
    cell.lblDescription.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.lblDescription.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.lblDescription sizeToFit];

    NSURL *candidateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:theCompany.Url];
    NSLog(@"%@", candidateURL);
    if (!(candidateURL && candidateURL.scheme && candidateURL.host)) {
        cell.lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

and this is the didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Company *company = [[Data getInstance].results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *candidateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:company.Url];
    if (candidateURL && candidateURL.scheme && candidateURL.host) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:company.Url]];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `cell.lblTitle.textColor = ...` what are the candidateURL property values that you are testing for validity?  In other words, is this a display issue or a logic issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set cell.lblTitle.textColor explicitly always, as you might dequeue a cell with black label.  So add an else clause and make sure you're setting cell.lblTitle.textColor to some value always:

```
if (!(candidateURL && candidateURL.scheme && candidateURL.host)) { 
   cell.lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]; 
else
   cell.lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:1];
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much. Vote up and accepting answer. Can you pls explain why is this happening? Why the current cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath does not inherit color from storyboard?

Comment: You're using only a single reusable cell name "StandardSearchResultCell", so you're getting recycled cells that may have blue or black labels when you scroll the table.  You could also solve this by using two different re-usable cell names

Comment: Oh, thx for the explanation. I have another problem with this tableview. After this explanation of yours I think that one as well can be related to the same issue somehow. Can you pls check this topic, if you can? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379401/multiline-label-in-custom-cell-overlaps-the-next-cell-when-scrolling-fast