# Multiline label in custom cell overlaps the next cell when scrolling fast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I see that similar question is asked almost dozens of times, but none of the answers solved my problem (or I'm just too tired so I'm not following answers correctly)

I have a tableview with custom cell.

The cell looks like this

[image: My custom cell in storyboard]

The cell is of type ResultsViewCell, which is derived from UITableViewCell.

Last label in the cell is multiline cell. That one sometimes overlaps contents of the next cell.

Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath function

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StandardSearchResultCell";

        ResultsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // Configure the cell...
        Data *theData = [Data getInstance];
        Company *theCompany = [theData.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.lblTitle.text = theCompany.DisplayName;

        cell.lblDescription.text = theCompany.Description;
        cell.lblAddressPt1.text = theCompany.AddressPt1;
        cell.lblAddressPt2.text = theCompany.AddressPt2;
        cell.lblPhone.text = theCompany.Phone;
        cell.lblEmail.text = theCompany.Email;

        cell.lblDescription.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false;
        cell.lblDescription.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.lblDescription.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.lblDescription sizeToFit];

       ///////////////////////////////////////////
       //edit -Added after David H's answer, but it didn't solve the problem
       cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false;
       UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
       CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(270.0f, MAXFLOAT);
       CGSize labelSize = [theCompany.Description sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
       [cell.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, 270, 90 + labelSize.height)];
       //end of edit
       ///////////////////////////////////////

        return cell;
    }


- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Data *theData = [Data getInstance];
    Company *theCompany = [theData.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(270.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [theCompany.Description sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return (90.0f + labelSize.height);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Haha, I'll try to be more careful about this. Pls help me now, if you can. Vote up for this warning.

Comment: Agree with @DavidH answer.  But I'm surprised this code works without handling the case where the deque returns nil.  Did you leave that out of the paste for brevity?

Comment: @danh makes a good point - I didn't really look at the whole method. Normally you would be recycling cells.

Comment: No, I really do not handle that situation. It never occurred so far. I'm trying to understand how to implement what DavidH said (I'm newbie on iOS, as you can see)

Comment: I take it that with the multi-line label in the cell, your cell height needs to adjust to what is in the contents so that the label lies within the cell. It that what you are going for?

Comment: No, I already have that solved (originally did not put heightForRowAtIndexPath function here, but now I added it to the post). It's shown correctly. It only gets messed up when I scroll it fast.

Comment: You should check for the cell variable in the beginning of the function to make sure it is not nil. also you should try to optimize the cell allocation/reuse

Comment: make sure your code is fast enough not to delay the UITable while scrolling.

Comment: This is self referring '[cell.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, 270, 90 + labelSize.height)];
' - the contentView height should be some defined value or not referring to itself.

Answer (score 1):

It might surprise you, but the default for the UIView property 'clipsToBounds' is NO - that is, if subviews extend past the frame of the view, show them anyway.

The fix is to insure that none of these views have 'clipsToBounds' set to NO. You should set it on cell.contentView to YES, and make sure that the frame of cell.contentView has the same height as you report back in the delegate 'heightForRowAtIndexPath:' method.

You may also need to set the 'clipsToBounds' to YES on the multiline label (not sure, probably not).

Comment: I think the cell contentView ought to be enough, since the property deals with treatment of subviews. +1 as usual.

Comment: I tried what I thought you told me to do. It did not help. I edited the original post so you can see what I did.

Comment: clipsToBounds = YES - that is, you want the container view to clip any subviews that would draw outside the view. I edited my post just after I posted it to make it clearer - you may have seen the first draft that did not make it so clear.

Comment: If I use clipping to bounds, then I lose some of the text in that last label. Can I just prevent text in the last label from going nuts when scrolled quickly?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to resize your `tableViewCell` height based on the text height of that label. for example take this method:

```
- (int)textHeight:(NSString *)text {
    int width = self.tableView.frame.size.width;
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 30)];
    label.numberOfLines = kMyNumberOfLines;

    //setup the label to look like the label of the cell

    label.text = text;
    [label sizeToFit];

    int h = (int)label.frame.size.height;
    [label release];
    return h;
}
```

then use that method in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to determine the height of your cell.

Answer (score 0):

Follow like this...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *myCell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"hi"];
    myCell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"hi"];

    if (myCell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *viewsToRemove = [mytable1 subviews];

        for (UITableView *table in viewsToRemove) 
        {
            [table removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }    
    return myCell;
}
```